# git pull origin master deleted my local files

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm new to git a made a mistake.

I've been trying to sync a local folder on my computer and tried to upload the files into a recently new folder in my gitlab account.
There were nothing inside the remote folder.

I did the following

```
git add .

git commit -m "Initial import"

git remote add origin git@gitlab.myaccount.com:gus/my-git-project

git init

git clone git@gitlab.myaccount.com:gus/my-git-project
Cloning into 'my-git-project'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 14, done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 14
Receiving objects: 100% (14/14), 11.00 KiB | 5.50 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.

git pull origin master
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 318, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
remote: Total 318 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 285
0.01 KiB | 889.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (318/318), 674.31 KiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (124/124), done.
From gitlab.myaccount.com:gus/my-git-project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Unfortunately, I misunderstood the process of git and remarked that the 14 objects that were present in my local folder were removed/deleted.

Finding a way to undo what I did, I've tested so far:

```
git reflog
d2cdbfd (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): Initial import


git checkout HEAD

git log
commit d2cdbfd924r45r76348903c6asvbd905c79bb32c (HEAD -> master)

git reset HEAD


git reset --hard
HEAD is now at eca6f91 Merge branch 'master' of gitlab.myaccount.com:gus/my-git-project

git reflog
eca6f91 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
eca6f91 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
eca6f91 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{2}: pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories: Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
d2cdbfd HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): Initial import
```

Any chance to get back those files? Any help would be very appreciated :).
Thanks!

Comment: I think `git checkout d2cdbfd` will get back your files.

Comment: Since you wanted to add to the existing branch in the repo, you should have started with clone (no init), *then* created your files, added them, committed the change. Finally, the change would be *pushed*.

Comment: thanks @ikegami but it didn't worked. I found however in the local repo a .git/objects which contains 14 folders. That could probably corresponds to the 14 that were deleted. However these are in a (binary?) format.

Comment: fixed!
I don't know exactly how but I could find back my files with some revert command.
A big thanks @ikegami